How to change User-Agent header in Expo Av video component?
I'm using Expo Av Video component to stream .m3u8 files in react native expo android application using this code:
const headers: Record<string, string> = {
    "User-Agent": "myApp228",
    "XXX-MY-HEADER": "my header value",
}

<Video
    ref={videoRef}
    style={styles.player}
    source={{
        uri: currentUri,
        headers: headers,
    }}
    shouldPlay={!paused}
    progressUpdateIntervalMillis={500}
    onLoadStart={_onLoadStart}
    onLoad={_onLoad}
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={_onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
    onError={_onError}
/>

I'm trying to use custom and overrided http headers, it works fine with custom headers like "XXX-MY-HEADER", but it doesn't overrides default "User-Agent" header.
screenshot of debugger
Is it possible to override default "User-Agent" header and how can I do it?
